# The messageCreate event isn't firing when privately DM'ing my Discord bot directly

Tags: discord, discord.js

When sending a personal message to my Discord bot, the event listener(s) that I have tried aren't firing. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');

const bot = new Client({
    partials: ["CHANNEL"],
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
    ]
}); // A list of the intents that my bot is currently using for other functionality on the server

bot.on('messageCreate', async msg => {
    console.log('message');
    // This DOES fires for user messages sent directly on the server only ...
    // Why does this not fire when a user sends a message to my bot in DM's?
});

// The below functionality used to work when using an old Discord.js version with the below code:

bot.on('message', async msg=>{
    console.log('message1'); // This no longer works
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked when I tried it, so I'm not able to test this solution, but taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275630), try adding `MESSAGE` to your partials array, and use the new [`Partial`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/Partials) enum:

```js
const { Partials } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({
    partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message],
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
    ]
});
```

If this still doesn't work, give me your exact discord.js version and I'll see if I can reproduce your problem - and given the fact that you've had to use the string literal "CHANNEL" for the partials array, I have a feeling your version might be outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I’ll give this a try when I get back to my machine. 

Comment: That's done the trick, adding the Partials.Channel and Partials.Message instead of hard coding the values. Thanks mate.